# If I 'cp' a file, is the 'atime' updated?

Tags: unix

If I 'cp' a file, is the 'atime' (access time) updated?

I want to find the last time a file was copied.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the atime (access time) on a file is modified when copied using the `cp` command. The resultant file will also have the same atime.

Your filesystem must also not be mounted with `noatime` (disables inode atime storage).

Comment: Assuming the filesystem isn't setup with noatime.